# Best way to deal with "key error" when scraping (yahoo finance)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

Hi I am making a scrape for yahoo finance and I am using JSON to get keys and then scraping the keys e.g ...

```
fwd_div_yield = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']["summaryDetail"]['dividendYield']['raw']
```

The error is that if a company doesn't pay a dividend it will produce a key error as there is no key 'raw' instead of using raw = 0 they just don't have raw. But if a company does have a dividend it will return 'raw', 'fmt' etc.

I was wondering what the most efficient way of dealing with this is?

Another Question Is how would you access ...

```
[{'raw': 1595894400, 'fmt': '2020-07-28'}, {'raw': 1596412800, 'fmt': '2020-08-03'}]
```

my current soloution is...

```
earnings_dates = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['calendarEvents']['earnings']['earningsDate'][0]['fmt']

earnings_datee = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['calendarEvents']['earnings']['earningsDate'][1]['fmt']

earnings_date = earnings_dates+", "+earnings_datee
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the dividend yield from the `raw` key and not get a `KeyError` when it's not there, do the following:

```
fwd_div_yield = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']["summaryDetail"]['dividendYield'].get('raw', 0)
```

In the event `raw` is not there, the `fwd_div_yield` will be 0.

Then to retrieve each date from the list of dictionaries, you can use a list comprehension:

```
earnings_dates = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['calendarEvents']['earnings']['earningsDate']
fmt_dates = [date['fmt'] for date in earnings_dates]
```

Also, this data is available via url:  https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/aapl?modules=summaryDetail.  Just replace `aapl` with the symbol you're scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap whatever code is checking if the company pays a dividend in a `try/except` block.

```py
def paysDivivend(data):
    try:
        if 'raw' in data:
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

Without seeing any example code this is a quick fix solution

For the second question...

**IF** you are asking to create `[{'raw': 1234,'fmt':'2020-07-28'},...]`:

Based on the compiled list of companies that pay a dividend.
Create a the list:

```py
def dividendList(data):
    dividend_list = []
    for company in data:
        dividend_list.append({'raw':compay['path']['to']['raw'],'fmt':company['path']['to'][fmt']})
    return dividend_list
```

**IF** you are trying to access each one after you already created the list:

```py
def accessDividend(dividend_data):
    for dividend in dividend_data:
        print(f"{dividend['raw']}, {dividend['fmt']}")
```

Comment: thanks regarding the second question essentially for that particular item it retuns two raws and two fmts I was asking is there a way to extract both the fmts in one line of code instead of spliting them both individually as above in my example and then creating a new variable including the two previous variable which split it

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of  `data` ? It seems `data...['earningsDate']` is a list of {'raw': ...'fmt': ... }` can use a very similar approach to my first suggestion just instead of a list of companies that pay dividends it's the `earningsDate` list for each of those companies.

Answer (score 0):

I created this method as a workaround.

```
def yfinanceDataframe(symbol, interval, _range):  
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

  data = requests.get(f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?interval={interval}&range={_range}', headers=headers).json()
  timestamp = data['chart']['result'][0]['timestamp']
  data = data['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]


  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df['Datetime'] = timestamp
  df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: dt.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
  df.dropna(inplace=True)
  df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  df.rename(columns={'close': 'Close'}, inplace=True)

  return df
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).